# File not properly closing using fcntl.h close

Tags: c, linux

Here is the code snippet below I am not sure why this doesnt work

but the output i get is

```
-1
-1
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{

    int fd = open("/home/felipe/gdelt/fixed/test.bin", O_APPEND|O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
    std::cout<<close(fd)<<std::endl;
    fd = open("/home/felipe/gdelt/fixed/test.bin", O_APPEND|O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
    std::cout<<fd<<std::endl;
    //testWrite();
    return 0;
}
```

Revised Code (Adding the mode is what made it work )

```
int main()
{

    int fd = open("/home/felipe/gdelt/fixed/test.bin", O_APPEND|O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,S_IWUSR);
    std::cout<<close(fd)<<std::endl;
    fd = open("/home/felipe/gdelt/fixed/test.bin", O_APPEND|O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,S_IWUSR);
    std::cout<<fd<<std::endl;
    //testWrite();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `O_CREAT` is specified, then a 3rd argument must be supplied to `open()`. Omitting it results in undefined behavior (maybe the function reads a garbage value from the stack and it can't do anything with the nonsensical arbitrary value it reads.)

Comment: As your code shows, the open is failing... so of course trying to close fd -1 will fail.

Comment: Print `fd` in a separate printing operation (`std::cout << fd << '\n';`) before closing the file.  And/or print `errno` or `strerror(errno)`.  It is also curious to see a C tag on code which is clearly C++; and it is curious that it is compiling without `<iostream>` being included -- presumably something, maybe `<stdio.h>`, is including it for you.

Comment: Are you writing C or C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quotes from `man 2 open`. You must specify the 3rd `mode` parameter when using the O_CREAT flag.

> ```
> int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
> int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
> ```
>
> mode specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is created.  This argument  must  be  supplied when  O_CREAT  is specified in flags; if O_CREAT is not specified, then mode is ignored.

It was your `open` syscall that failed in the first place. `close` only failed because you tried to use it on invalid file descriptor -1.

Comment: thanks i changed the code to include the mode and this worked proplery